# Can't print mpdf generated pdf files on mac

Tags: macos, pdf, printing, preview, acrobat

This is really weird. I generate pdf using mpdf. I had no problem with printing pdfs. But suddenly this problem appeared. Not sure it is something to do with change of my code or updating my operating system or wireless printer printer.

**System-------------Application-------Result** 
OS X 10.8.2---------Preview----------can't print
OS X 10.8.2---------Acrobat----------can print
OS X 10.7.x----------Reader----------can't print
Windows XP-----Reader/Dont know----can print
OS X 10.X.X---------Preview---------can't print

Some information:
We was able to print pdf before. There wasn't any complain from any OS/person.
I was working on some sql query changes. But I undo my things. still not working.

So what it says when someone try to print using "Preview"
-On my macbook pro it says (Printing - Connected to printing. and stays like this)
-Probably on other mac it also shows like happening something...but nothing happens.
FYI we don't get any confirmation like....printing completed....it is like printing..and printing.

There was a application PDFRepair. And after repairing with this application. I can print my pdf. But problem is its not freeware and quality is not good.

Maybe it is broken/damaged content issue.

Goal: Goal is print our pdf files with "Preview"

Any kinds of help or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

[image: screenshot of my pdf]

Comment: if you open Console.app, are there any helpful hints or warnings being printed there?

Comment: Yes, it says many things. sure I do not understand what they mean. Here is screenshot [link](http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1xcEMlk98k3NsCZJH8L8HObcIvZLL)

Comment: Your console output link says "`Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pixdb.pixentral.com' (4) in /home/pixentra/functions/master.php on line 4
I cannot connect to the database because: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'pixdb.pixentral.com' (4)`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved. That was something to do with mPDF CMap resource stuffs. But it happens with only mPDF older version. In my case it was mPDF 5.0 Beta.

**Using mPDF latest version will solve this problem**. Now I can print my exported pdf from any OS and any application. Cheers